# GoogleCalendarAPI to insert events giving Rails--[API Error]: --{:error=>["Excon::Error::Forbidden", "Expected([200]) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)\n"]}

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console, excon

I have been using Google calendar API to insert events in user's calendar. I have written a code which takes csv(with approx 1000 rows) as an input with minimum required parameters to create events such as event_title, event_description, event_date (since its a full day event) and recipient email id..The code runs in background using sidekiq.

Out of 1000 rows , only some events are inserted in user's calendar. Most of them are giving Rails -- [API Error]: -- {:error=>["Excon::Error::Forbidden", "Expected([200]) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)\n"]} error.

I have been using excon client (gem) to hit the urls to refresh token and inserting an event.

Token is refreshed
Loop (
Hitting API to insert events
)
rescue error

end

I couldnt figure out what's going wrong ?..Any help is appreciated. While registering my app in Google developer console , I have given the full scope of calendar api  auth/calendar.

I tried setting Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false.
Implementing such api first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 403 would indicate that the permissions are not valid in some way. My guesses would be that either the token is expiring, you are hitting some kind of rate limit, or something is different about the parameters for the failing request such that the particular event is not allowed.

Do you think any of those is more likely than the others? If it is the token expiring, you could try to catch the 403 error, refresh the token, and retry. If it's one of the others it might take a bit more digging to see why the ones that are failing are different from the ones that succeed.

Comment: Thanks geemus...I was hitting the rate limit also i found calendar limit usage exceeded.

Comment: Yep, that would make sense. Thanks for reporting back. I guess you may need to slow down or spread out how you are doing these to avoid the rate limit.